# Querying across multiple Google Spreadsheets with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am working with JavaScript in a Google Spreadsheet and I would like to query another Google Spreadsheet.

The following link shows you how to query the data from client-side JavaScript, but does anyone know how it can be done within the Google Spreadsheet JavaScript?

http://blog.ouseful.info/2009/05/18/using-google-spreadsheets-as-a-databace-with-the-google-visualisation-api-query-language/

Query I want to execute:

[http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select%20*&key=phNtm3LmDZEObQ2itmSqHIA](http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out%3ahtml&tq=select%20%2a&key=phNtm3LmDZEObQ2itmSqHIA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UrlFetch Services](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/service_urlfetch.html) was what I was looking for.